# How does one encrypt a georeferenced PDF map

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, geopdf, avenza

As a hobby I make georeference PDF maps on QGIS and use it on Avenza Maps for hiking trails remote reserves. Is there anyway to encrypt the map so it cannot be shared? I put many hours into a map project and do not want the map to be able to be shared without my permission.

Comment: It's just a file so any encryption tool can encrypt it - the real question is can Avenza unencrypt it?

Answer (score 2):

Maps downloaded from Avenza are locked in root directories and not available to the users outside of the Avenza PDF Maps application. A phone or tablet owner who has rooted their Android device (or jail braked an iPhone) would have access to the actual PDF files.

It is not necessary to post a geospatial PDF to Avenza to use it with the Avena PDF Maps phone app.  You can download from your personal Dropbox (iOS or Android), move it to a phone directory on Android using your PC, or move make it available to Avenza using iTunes for iOS.  This would be the best method to ensure your PDF map was secure.

If you want to make a geospatial PDF available outside of Avenza (maybe posted to your website?) but do not want others to use them you could place them into a password protected ZIP file using 7Zip.  A strongly worded end  user agreement and copyright statement might prevent some from sharing or distributing your maps.

Comment: On the Avenza app, if you click on the 3 dots to the right (android) you can now share the map with others. So I was wondering if there was away to encrypt the map not to be shared. With this share function, if I send the map to a someone to use on Avenza, that person would be able to send it others now.

Comment: I think this sharing is only available for custom imported maps not maps from the Avenza Map store.  Why not just post them to the map store and charge money for them?  I find that reduces the number of downloads considerably.